# Summation of a 2d list

Tags: python

I am having trouble adding up each row in a 2d list.

Here is the problem:We will pass in a 2 dimensional list of numbers. 
You should: 1 . add up all the numbers in each row and output that number and 2. output the grand total of all rows.

Below is my code so far:

```
    import sys
    numbers= sys.argv[1:]


    for i in range(0,len(numbers)): 
      numbers[i]= numbers[i].split(',')
    total = 0
    sum = 0
    for row in range(len(numbers)):
      sum += (row)
      total += (sum)
      print(sum)
    print(total)
```

Here is what my output and the expected output is:

Program Output

```
Program Failed for Input: 1,1,-2 -1,-2,-3 1,1,1
Expected Output: 0
-6
3
-3

Your Program Output: 0
1
3
4
```

Your output was incorrect. Try again.

As you can see, I have everything correct except for the 2nd row which is adding all negative numbers which is then affecting the grand total at the end. Do I need add negative numbers differently?

Thanks for you input!

Comment: `for row in range(len(numbers)):` is not using the values of `numbers` (which need to be converted as integers since they're strings)

Comment: Don't name your variables sum, [sum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) is python builtin function which you override by naming your variables like that.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to (after splitting your input by ',') change splitted values from strings to integers and then you could use python builtin function [sum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) to add them all up.

```
import sys

numbers= sys.argv[1:]

total = 0
for i in numbers:
    row_sum = sum([int(i) for i in i.split(',')])
    total += row_sum
    print(row_sum)
print(total)
```

Output:

```
0
-6
3
-3
```

Comment: You forgot to calculate and output the rows total.